# What happens if you kill a bash script containing a single nohup command?

Tags: linux, bash, nohup

I have just learned about `nohup` which is so far very useful - my jobs aren't crashing due to my ssh session unintentionally disconnecting.

Can someone tell me what happens if I do `ctrl-C` after submitting a `nohup` job? I'm hoping it continues to run. After starting the job it says

```
$ nohup: appending output to ‘nohup.out'
```

But it does not take me to a fresh line of input to do other commands.

Can anyone explain why the `&` is necessary at the end of my command?

```
nohup sh -c 'for file in ../orig_data/merged/*Inp*.gz; do zcat $file | bowtie2 -p 8 -q -x hg_mm -U - -S "${file:20:-9}".sam; done' &
```

---

EDIT:This nohup command is within a bash script executed as `./job.sh`. So if I kill this bash script, does it also kill my nohup command?

Comment: & runs your command as a background process (i.e. outside your shell). You need to read up on this.

Comment: BTW, in general, well-written bash has no need to use `nohup`; everything `nohup` can do, you can do yourself with redirections and the `disown` command -- and doing the redirections yourself means you have more control over where logs are emitted to.

Comment: When you say "does not take you to a fresh line of input" -- that fresh line of input was the `$` at the beginning of your line of output. Because of the `&`, nohup is run **in the background**, so the prompt is printed **before** `nohup` is finished starting up. If you just press enter again, you'll get a new prompt.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks. I was told to use nohup to avoid my jobs dying due to ssh disconnections. See the edit for why I don't get a `$` after running this command

Comment: I linked this to a separate duplicate that explains that. That said, the person who told you to use nohup arguably didn't know bash particularly well; it can be necessary with `sh` (a more limited shell), but `bash` is more capable.

Comment: Consider for example: `for file in ../orig_data/merged/*Inp*.gz; do bowtie2 -p 8 -q -x hg_mm -U - -S "${file:20:-9}".sam < <(zcat "$file") & disown -h "$!"; done >bowtie.log 2>&1 </dev/null`; note that that should only be run in code with a `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, `#!/bin/bash`, or other bash shebang, **not** run with `sh`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you this is very helpful to see written out

Answer (score 0):

The & sign at the end of any shell command puts your process in the background so you can continue interacting with your terminal, and at the same time, your command executes in the background.

Comment: Did you mean `&`?

Comment: I guess you mean "The & sign", not "The $ sign" :)

Comment: Yes. Edited my answer. Was typing on my phone. Hard to press thr right key.

Comment: The nohup command I posted was within a bash script, so that must be why it doesn't appear to be going in the background and I can't type new commands. Will my nohup command stop if I kill the script?

Comment: Regardless. If you have a next command after your nohup (with &), it should execute right away.